# Disable Button when integer value

Tags: java, javafx

I tried disable button when some integer value != 1

For example (my idOrder is IntegerProperty)

```
    refreshButton.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {

        @Override
        protected boolean computeValue() {
            return currentOrder.getIdOrder() != 1;
        }
    });
```

And it's works. But when I changed value on 1 (currentOrder.setIdOrder(1)) button is still disabled.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a JavaFX property associated with `getIdOrder()` (e.g. `IntegerProperty`)? Or at least an `Observable`? (providing a [mre] would make such questions unnecessary, by the way).

Comment: Sorry i made mistake in topic. My idOrder is IntegerProperty and getIdOrder() just returning integer from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a `BooleanBinding` but haven't configured it to observe anything, thus it will never be notified of your property changing. You need to invoke [`BooleanBinding#bind(Observable...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/BooleanBinding.html#bind(javafx.beans.Observable...)) during instantiation. For example:

```java
refreshButton.disableProperty().bind(new BooleanBinding() {

  {
    bind(currentOrder.idOrderProperty());
  }

  @Override protected boolean computeValue() {
    return currentOrder.getIdOrder() != 1;
  }

  @Override public void dispose() {
    // for a proper implementation, we need this as well
    unbind(currentOrder.idOrderProperty());
  }
});
```

That said, the above can be simplified with [`Bindings#createBooleanBinding(Callable,Observable...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createBooleanBinding(java.util.concurrent.Callable,javafx.beans.Observable...)):

```java
refreshButton.disableProperty()
    .bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
        () -> currentOrder.getIdOrder() != 1, currentOrder.idOrderProperty()));
```

But even that can be simplified further with one of the following:

- [`Bindings#notEqual(int,ObservableNumberValue)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#notEqual(int,javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue)):

  ```java
  refreshButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.notEqual(1, currentOrder.idOrderProperty());
  ```
- [`NumberExpresion#isNotEqualTo(int)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpressionBase.html#isNotEqualTo(int)):

  ```java
  refreshButton.disableProperty().bind(currentOrder.idOrderProperty().isNotEqualTo(1));
  ```